# Why does this JavaScript bookmarklet clear the page?

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with JavaScript bookmarklet code.  I want to

1. clear the tab  content
2. change the background colour
3. change the font colour
4. make the  element editable

When I run this code

```
javascript:document.body.style.background='darkslategray';
document.body.style.color='linen';
document.body.innerHTML='';
document.body.contentEditable=true;
```

I get a white page.  It doesn't matter which order I use the commands.  When I run them one by one in the console I get the result I want.  A grey page with light font colour I can type in.

Comment: There must be some kind of timing issue with what you are doing. Usually that suggests that you are approaching it the wrong way. I would think that you want some kind of form, with a textedit field for your input?

Comment: I see the downvote.  I see it is anonymous.  I see that the downvoter has not answered my question, pointed out why it merits a downvote, helped me to answer my question, or been constructive in any way.  I note the reasons to downvote a question: viz, 'This question does not show any research effort' => no,  'It is unclear' => 'It is not very useful'=>hard to judge.  I wonder why StackOverflow has become so cynical. Playing with code should be fun, I find it fun, from play and experiment comes innovation. Stamping on play is negative, and (at least where I come from) unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarklets can't run a series of statements unless they are in a function, which is called when the bookmarklet is called.

The answer is to wrap the commands in an anonymous function.

This bookmarklet code will run as a bookmark when the bookmark is called or as a link in a page when the link is clicked. It clears the tab html, and inserts a div to type into.

```
javascript:(function(){ 
  document.body.innerHTML = 'make notes here'; 
  document.title='your new note';
  var divvy = document.createElement("div"); 
  document.body.appendChild(divvy); 
  divvy.style.background='darkslategray'; 
  divvy.style.color='linen'; 
  divvy.contentEditable=true; 
  divvy.textContent = 'write here' 
})()
```